# Phrase/expression meaning "negative parts"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I consulted [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bad%20part), but I didn't find anything useful.

Example sentence:

> I fiddled with my wedding ring, thinking about __ of my marriage.

Comment: Start your thesaurus search with *flaw*.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you consider to fall within the description of "negative parts"? Otherwise we have to guess what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to naturally speak this sentence out loud, my kneejerk response would instantly go to the word "shortcoming", used in the plural form here.

> I fiddled with my wedding ring, thinking about all the **shortcomings** of my marriage.

Again, just naturally it would come out that way, and you'd be right to call me out on using 'all' there giving the implication that things are quite dire, but it's what sounds most natural; the sentence by virtue of context lends itself to things being pretty serious which in this case is this person's seemingly growing worries and doubts.

There are plenty of other things you could go with, even just taking it pure natural everyday talk, throw out grammar books, and use ways such as:

> I fiddled with my wedding ring, thinking about all the **worst stuff** of my marriage.

But, for every day use, both in casual and polite situations, or especially in some business talk such as sports when remarking about say a given player on a team — that word would be what sounds most accurate, appropriate, and more importantly, natural.

But, just to specifically address that you asked for a phrase or expression, see if this works for you:

> I fiddled with my wedding ring, thinking about all the **negative aspects** of my marriage.

Before you jump the gun, I know I am using one of the words you used in part of your question, 'negative', but to be perfectly honest that is about the most natural way it can be expressed in every day casual and/or formal situations to mean 'negative parts'. In this case, you literally just about picked up the answer with your own question, by accident. Kind of feel like maybe this was on the tip of your tongue but you just couldn't nail it down, or maybe I'm just a raving lunatic reading too much into it! Ha!

Hope this helps, and feel free to give me a slap on the wrist if this was totally off-base with what you were looking for!

Comment: If the negative element in question was an inability to last in bed, then *shortcomings* might be even more appropriate.